# google api places get real types not the other

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Hi all, I have a web-site where I would like to make a search of places with google maps api possible.

***For example:*** I would like to search for an airport in London, but as the code shows, I don't end up with the proper results.

**This is my code:** I pass latitude and longitude of London and should output all airports on the map within a radius of 10km:

```
var request = {
    location: latlng,
    radius: '10000',
    types: ["airport"]
};

    var callPlaces = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
    callPlaces.search(request, function(results,status){
        if(results != null){
            $.each(results, function(i,place){
                console.log(place.name
            }
        }
    }
```

this is the result:

```
The London Heliport Ltd
Kensington Cars
Uptown Cars Ltd
Tottenham Hale Station
Clock Cars Ltd
Self Storage - Vanguard
Airport Transfers Company
Eastend Cars
Costa Minicab Services
Tiptop
Tiger Cars
Clapham Airport Cars
london taxi service
No 1 Traveller Ltd
London Classic Cars
Airport Taxis
AAA Airport Transfers
Battersea Airport Cars
Airport Car Hire Limited
AAA Cars
```

Has you can see there is many result that aren't airport. How can I solve?

Comment: Problem is that any of those results is 'correct'. Each of them has place type `airport` and also many others. For example `No 1 Traveller Ltd` has `travel_agency, parking, airport, transit_station, lodging, establishment`.

Comment: ok but any of this has only types airport. Every result has many type not? @AntoJurković

Comment: Any of them has type airport. Even taxy service. And many other types too.

Comment: ok but how to select only real airport? @AntoJurković

Comment: Try option rankby PROMINENCE

Comment: It seems that much better results are get using option `query: 'airport near london'` and `textSearch()`. Using that I got only 3 results: Heathrow, London City Airport and London Biggin Hill Airport. And what is interesting, all of them has type `airport` as the first one of types.

Comment: ok perfect, I'm searching also for the other types, because I have many button: airports, park, museum. Every time I click a button I would like to search its types. Is possible to use query in thiw way for museum, park ecc...? @AntoJurković